# REQUEST_METHOD changed to 'POST_method=POST'

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

When doing a post from a form, the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is `POST_method=POST`, when I do a normal get request the value is `GET`. This was never the case, and changed after I updated my server.

I am almost sure that the value is supposed to be `POST`

Example:

```
'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST_method=POST',
```

I am using CakePHP and on deletes where `$this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');`is set, I get an error of `Method not allowed`, which I understand, because the method is not POST.

Does anyone know where this is set on the server or in the php config?

### Update 1:

If I submit this form:

```
<form action="/sources/select_categories/10" id="SourceCategorySelectCategoriesForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>
<div class="submit"><input  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Select Categories"/></div>
</form>
```

I get:

```
'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST_method=POST',
```

and the posted values are:

```
array(
'_method' => 'POST_method=POST'
)
```

And if I submit this form:

```
<form action="/sources/select_categories/10" id="SourceCategorySelectCategoriesForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[SourceCategory][category_ids][]"  value="5" id="SourceCategoryCategoryIds"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[SourceCategory][category_ids][]"  value="6" id="SourceCategoryCategoryIds"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[SourceCategory][category_ids][]"  value="4" id="SourceCategoryCategoryIds"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[SourceCategory][category_ids][]"  value="3" id="SourceCategoryCategoryIds"/>
<div class="submit"><input  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Select Categories"/></div></form>
```

I get:

```
'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST',
```

But the received values are:

```
array(
'_method' => 'POST',
'data' => array(
    'SourceCategory' => array(
        'category_ids' => array(
            (int) 0 => '5',
            (int) 1 => '6',
            (int) 2 => '4',
            (int) 3 => '3_method=POST',
            (int) 4 => '5',
            (int) 5 => '6',
            (int) 6 => '4',
            (int) 7 => '3'
        )
    )
)
)
```

So something weird is going on. When the form is empty of any fields, The Request method changes, and if I have fields, the field values looks all funny.

Any suggestions what could be causing this?

### UPDATE 2:

I just tried a form on in it's own php file, bypassing cakephp all together

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
<input type="submit" value="Select Categories"/>
</form>
```

The $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] stays "POST", but a print_r($_POST) renders:

```
Array
(
    [_method] => POST_method=POST
)
```

So it seems that it must be php or apache that is changing the post variable "_method" and then CakePHP changes the $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"].

This is making me clueless, and I don't know where to start with this. Maybe uninstall php and apache?

### Update 3

Form 1

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="x" value="y"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Gives

```
Array
(
    [x] => yx=y
)
```

Form 2:

```
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="x" value="y"/>
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="b"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [x] => y
    [a] => b
)
```

So if a single hidden value is posted, regardless of the name, it gets changed, if 2 values are posted, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: What cakephp version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.3

Comment: But it's doing it on all my installs of CakePHP, 2.2 and 2.3. It must be something in PHP or Apache that changed, and I am not sure what

Comment: `_method` is a field used to simulate other HTTP verbs with a (post) form. Check your source files for `POST_method`, that string is coming from somewhere and it's not in an unmodified CakePHP. From the description it may be javascript that's munging your form values - expecially from this: `'3_method=POST',`

Comment: I just created a new virtualhost, with nothing but the form, and the value is still changed. It also happens in all browsers, so its not an extension of some sort. Did a HTTPFOX on the request, and the value being submitted to the server is clean.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed it, although I still have no idea what caused it.

I un installed PHP

```
sudo apt-get -y purge php*
```

Then installed PHP

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Then all my libs

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
sudo apt-get install php5-xmlrpc
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

And after all that it still works. Not sure if I have forgotten anything, but everything seems to work again.

I would still like to know what php lib caused the variables to be changed.

Thanks for all the input from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The value is being set in [`CakeRequest::_processPost()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.2/lib/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php#L164).

It retreives the value from either the `HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE` environment variable (which originates from the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` HTTP header), or from the `_method` POST field. The latter is automatically defined in an hidden field by the `FormHelper` class (see [`FormHelper::create()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.10/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L413), [`FormHelper::postList()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.10/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L1768)).

You'll have to do some debugging, check whether you are sending the mentioned header, look through the HTML source of your form, the `_method` field should by default only contain `POST` or `PUT`. If there's something else in the field then check whether you are maybe passing the `method` option to the helper methods (though in that case the value should be all uppercase).

Comment: Please see my code update in the original question, it really does not make any sense